# What is the header for the clock for iPod/iPhone? jailbreak development?

Tags: ios, timer, header, jailbreak, clock

Does anybody know what the header is for the clock app for iPods/iPhones? (jailbreak development)

Answer (score 0):

Install class-dump from cydia and run it like this:

```
class-dump -H /Applications/MobileTimer.app/MobileTimer -o /path/to/output
```

And it will dump the headers for all the classes in the clock app to the path you gave as output.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but the project has been closed. :(